# TypeScript in VS 2013 not giving me intellisense for my own class

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, but I'm just using it to get the tooling for javascript (I'm not using TypeScript features at this time). I thought I would get intellisense even if I was using normal javascript (and I sort of do), but the following example won't bring up the intellisense for my Person object. It doesn't show me anything after I place the dot after bob. Is it supposed too? What am I doing wrong?

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// init vars
Person.prototype.name = "";
Person.prototype.age = 0;

Person.prototype.haveBirthday = function () {
    this.age++;
};

var bob = new Person("bob", 34);

alert(bob.age);   /// it never showed me age or anything else is a property of bob

bob.haveBirthday();

alert(bob.age);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not infer class shapes from prototype assignments.

Comment: Whoa!! cannot believe this! This was one of the reasons I started to consider Typescript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a TypeScript file for Intellisense for a pure JavaScript file (as you mention that you're not using TypeScript).

If you just use a standard JavaScript file (with a .js extension) inside of Visual Studio 2013, Intellisense works correctly (as you had wanted).

Comment: I thought part of the reason typescript existed was because of tooling for stuff like intellisense?

Comment: Maybe to make it more consistent, but intellisense support was just one goal for Typescript. Having used the JavaScript intellisense support in Visual Studio for many versions, I'd say it's gotten quite good.